# Why doesn't this simple QRegExp match?

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

Very simply, here is test code which fails.

```
QRegExp BASIC_FORMAT ("^\\s*(.+?)\\s*,\\s*(.+)\\s*$");
QString test = "Catherine the Great, Szczecin 2/5/1729 to Saint Petersburg 17/11/1796";

qDebug ("%i", BASIC_FORMAT .indexIn (test));
```

This prints -1, although if I copy the strings into something like regex101.com (resolving double-backslashes myself, of course) then it matches as expected.

Why is QRegExp not matching in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QRegExp does not support non-greedy quantifiers like `+?`

You could use `[^,]+` instead